# ACI not receiving UDP communication

Tags: .net, azure, udp, azure-container-instances

I wanted to have a container hosted in Azure Container Instance listening to incoming logs on UDP port. I have developed docker image which works locally and in my company's internal network. Wanted to test it in Azure, but I'm not receiving any packets... But when I checked UDP connection with sample UDP listener from github it worked fine (I used that one:
[mendhak/docker-udp-listener](https://github.com/mendhak/docker-udp-listener)).

What concerns me is that I have 0 bytes received on my target container instance. It looks like ports would have been closed.

ACI deployed with script: 
`az container create --resource-group <resource_group> --name sidecar --image <my_repository>/sidecar:latest --ip-address Public --ports 7777 --protocol UDP -e "UdpPort=7777"`

At this point I'm a bit clueless what's going on.

Here is NetworkBytesReceivedPerSecond metric from Azure. Through that time I've sent couple request.

```
2022-07-15 08:14:00  Network Bytes Received Per Second  0.0
2022-07-15 08:15:00  Network Bytes Received Per Second  0.0
2022-07-15 08:16:00  Network Bytes Received Per Second  0.0
2022-07-15 08:17:00  Network Bytes Received Per Second  0.0
2022-07-15 08:18:00  Network Bytes Received Per Second  0.0
2022-07-15 08:19:00  Network Bytes Received Per Second  0.0
2022-07-15 08:20:00  Network Bytes Received Per Second  0.0
2022-07-15 08:21:00  Network Bytes Received Per Second  0.0
2022-07-15 08:22:00  Network Bytes Received Per Second  0.0
2022-07-15 08:23:00  Network Bytes Received Per Second  0.0
2022-07-15 08:24:00  Network Bytes Received Per Second  0.0
2022-07-15 08:25:00  Network Bytes Received Per Second  0.0
2022-07-15 08:26:00  Network Bytes Received Per Second  0.0
2022-07-15 08:27:00  Network Bytes Received Per Second  0.0
2022-07-15 08:28:00  Network Bytes Received Per Second  0.0
2022-07-15 08:29:00  Network Bytes Received Per Second  0.0
2022-07-15 08:30:00  Network Bytes Received Per Second  0.0
2022-07-15 08:31:00  Network Bytes Received Per Second  0.0
2022-07-15 08:32:00  Network Bytes Received Per Second  0.0
2022-07-15 08:33:00  Network Bytes Received Per Second  0.0
2022-07-15 08:34:00  Network Bytes Received Per Second  0.0
2022-07-15 08:35:00  Network Bytes Received Per Second  0.0
2022-07-15 08:36:00  Network Bytes Received Per Second  0.0
2022-07-15 08:37:00  Network Bytes Received Per Second  0.0
2022-07-15 08:38:00  Network Bytes Received Per Second
2022-07-15 08:39:00  Network Bytes Received Per Second  0.0
2022-07-15 08:40:00  Network Bytes Received Per Second  0.0
2022-07-15 08:41:00  Network Bytes Received Per Second
2022-07-15 08:42:00  Network Bytes Received Per Second  0.0
2022-07-15 08:43:00  Network Bytes Received Per Second  0.0
2022-07-15 08:44:00  Network Bytes Received Per Second  0.0
2022-07-15 08:45:00  Network Bytes Received Per Second  0.0
```

And it looks that port 7777 is truly opened in UDP
(output of `nestat -a` from inside of container):

```
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
udp6       0      0 0.0.0.0:7777            [::]:*                             
Active UNIX domain sockets (servers and established)
Proto RefCnt Flags       Type       State         I-Node   Path
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     5013     /tmp/dotnet-diagnostic-19-1606-socket
```

My Socket implementation:

```
        public async Task Listen(CancellationToken cancelToken)
        {
            IPEndPoint localEndpoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, _port);

            UdpSocket = new Socket(SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
            UdpSocket.Bind(localEndpoint);
            await ReceiveAsync(cancelToken);
        }

        private async Task ReceiveAsync(CancellationToken cancelToken)
        {
            byte[] buffer = GC.AllocateArray<byte>(65527, pinned: true);
            Memory<byte> bufferMemory = buffer.AsMemory();

            while (!cancelToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                try
                {
                    SocketReceiveFromResult result = await UdpSocket.ReceiveFromAsync(bufferMemory, SocketFlags.None, _blankEndpoint);
                    if (result.ReceivedBytes > 0)
                    {
                        byte[] relevantBuffer = bufferMemory.Slice(0, result.ReceivedBytes).ToArray();
                        string message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(relevantBuffer);
                        _onMessageReceived(result, message);
                    }
                }
                catch (SocketException)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After couple days I checked the communication again and the container receives messages. Everything seems to work fine. Looks like it was some Azure unavailability...
My configuration was correct. Problem solved.